# Setting build path in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, build, path

I have searched stackoverflow before posting this question.

In eclipse i am running a tomcat server. I deleted the .class files from the work folder of the tomcat server. From then on I am facing the issue saying the class couldnot be found. 
I re-built the project. Didnt help

Can you please suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you re-publish your project to tomcat? also check that if you have beans and servlets than are they build in the WEB-INF/classes folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT run Tomcat as a normal program inside Eclipse.  You should use the EE version of Eclipse, and then add Tomcat in the server view.  This will allow you to deploy Dynamic Web Projects directly to Tomcat or any other supported server.

Comment: Also, you can right-click the server name in the server view and select "Clean Tomcat Work Directory" which I would think is preferable to manually cleaning the work directory.

Answer (score 0):

delete the server from eclipse server view and create it again.